# How to break out a program flow of a method that returns a different type?

Tags: c#

I am running into somewhat of a particularly groiblesoe issue, i need to break out of my code if my code fails, but my method below expects an Arraylist as a return and not just a normal "return", how can i go about breaking out?

```
       public ArrayList ReadCLientDetailsFromFile(string clientCsvfileName)
    {
        List<string> numbersFromTheFile = new List<string>();

        using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(clientCsvfileName))
        {
            int lineCount = 0;

            while (!file.EndOfStream)
            {
                Client client = new Client();
                lineCount++;

                string lineFromFile = file.ReadLine();
                string [] strValue = lineFromFile.Split(';');

                var commas = strValue.Count();
                if (commas < 3 || commas >4)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("There is more than 4 values on line "+ lineCount + "\nThe Operation will abort");
                    break; //exit the code here


                }
                else
                {
                    client.clientCode = strValue[0];
                    client.depositId4 = strValue[1];
                    client.depositId5 = strValue[2];
                    client.errorType = strValue[3];

                    //put initial checks checks here and set defaults. 0
                    _clientCollectionList.Add(client);
                }


            }

            MessageBox.Show(_clientCollectionList.Count.ToString());
            return _clientCollectionList;

        }



    }
```

Comment: Throw an Exception instead of displaying the messagebox. Catch the exception somewhere up the call hierarchy and display the message there.

Comment: So if code run to fail, what do you want to return? If nothing want to return, you can just `return null`

Comment: @KlausGütter exception instead of simple return is always a bad choice, this can be logically returned

Comment: @MrinalKamboj I disagree. The file read does not conform to the expected format, so this is an error condition and should IMHO be reported as FileFormatException. There are numerous other exceptions that might be thrown by the code (e.g. FileNotFoundException) and I would prefer to handle them in a uniform way.

Comment: if the file doesn't confirm to a pattern, then it shall throw an inbuilt exception, which needs to be handled in the calling layers, but for a logical pattern, which can be deduced, throwing an exception is always a bad practice. Flow goes out of regular execution path, looking for an handler, which could have been handled logically  and without corrupting the current system state. That's where functional programming does a much better job

Comment: I would like some context about the caller. What is the caller going to do with the result? Just iterate through it? Do any checks on it? Modify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most conventional way to do it is to throw an exception from the place you've encountered an error and handle it in the code, that calls the method

```
public ArrayList ReadCLientDetailsFromFile(string clientCsvfileName)
{
    //some code
    if (commas < 3 || commas >4)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("There are more than 4 values on line "+ lineCount + "\nThe 
        Operation will abort");
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("There is more than 4 values on line "+ 
        lineCount); //exit the code here
    }
    //rest of the code
}
```

And in the calling code:

```
try
{
    ArrayList clientDetails = ReadCLientDetailsFromFile(clientCsvfileName);
}
catch
{
    //some exception handling
}
```

Another way is to pass an ArrayList to your method as a parameter and make a method to return bool on success/fail

```
public bool TryReadCLientDetailsFromFile(ArrayList dest, string clientCsvfileName)
{
    //some logic
    if (commas < 3 || commas >4)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There is more than 4 values on line "+ lineCount + "\nThe Operation will abort");
            return false //exit the code here
        }
    //rest of the logic, sussess
    return true
}
```

Comment: thank you, this was the most comprehensive response, and putting the exception there also protects me from any unseen issues.

Comment: @AshleyNesh replacing logic by exception or using exception for logical processing is a bad programming choice, please refrain

Comment: @MrinalKamboj it's not actually a logic. If the data, read from the file comes in an unappropriated format, this is an unexpected behaviour, which means an exception.

Comment: @ДмитроІванов that's a difference between Validation and Exception, here you are using a logical construct to figure out an exception, when a Validation would do a better job here in informing the caller. Exception ideally, especially the standard one like ArgumentException is the job of a File parsing / reading API, not the user program

Answer (score 1):

> public ArrayList ReadCLientDetailsFromFile(string clientCsvfileName)

**Still using `ArrayList`, this was in .Net 1.+ versions and has since been replaced by `List<T>` and numerous other data structures introduced, time to align with current day .Net framework, which is ahead by only 15+ years**

> Regarding your question

It just needs a return value, simply create a return value, which can return with a default value like null, if no value is filled in or there's no explicit initialization, in you case you have `_clientCollectionList`, but where is it initiated, simple return the same with a default / current value, it is all about code compilation

Answer (score 0):

Here you have 2 options available

1. Do **Exception Handling** Here , means throw Exception and handle it wherever you calling it.
2. return **null**